# как сделать микшер для задания диапозона цен?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]как сделать на js что то подобное? 
возможно ли как то стилизовать и выводить данные с помощью стандартного input type="range"?

или может быть есть какие то готовые решения для react?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Я использую react-input-range.

Описание компонента [здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-range)

```
 <InputRange
      draggableTrack
      maxValue={20}
      minValue={0}
      onChange={value => this.setState({ value5: value })}
      onChangeComplete={value => console.log(value)}
      value={this.state.value5} />
```

Ссылка на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/davidchin/full/GpNvqw/)

Comment: а как его стилизовать?

Comment: @DmitryFilippov перейдите по ссылке на CodePen - скопируйте исходник себе и поправьте как вам нужно

Comment: просто не очень ясно как менять стили для него. вот что у меня. добавил фото

Comment: @DmitryFilippov подгрузите стандартные стили от этого компонента из SCSS и модифицируйте как вам нужно. Или проще всего из режима разработки вашего любимого браузера скопируйте себе скомпиленный стиль и поправьте все, что нужно